# SceneDelegate in iOS 13, Is it necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, uiscenedelegate

I have an app that was initially written with minimum iOS target of iOS 11

After adding new features and support for iOS 13, the recent version now requires minimum iOS target of iOS 13.
There is no SceneDelegate in my project at all and still the app is working perfectly as expected.
Also the app doesn't require multi window support. It is still a single window app.

Is it necessary to add SceneDelegate to this project? Will it cause any problem in future if no SceneDelegate is added?

Comment: No, its not necessary. Have a look at. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/specifying_the_scenes_your_app_supports